# Read-off particle from (projected) Dynkin labels

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, group-theory, unified-theories

In the review of Slanksy "Group theory for unified model building" in chapter 6:
How do one relate the projected Dynkin diagrams from for example $\overline{5}+10$ of $su(5)$ to the corresponding representation in of the subgroup $su(2)\times su(3)$?

An example is 
$P( 0 0 1)=(0)(01)$, how do one see that this must be a charge $1/3$ antiquark singlet?

Reference: http://cds.cern.ch/record/134739/files/198109187.pdf?origin=publication_detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first set of parentheses contains the $SU(2)$ weight. It being $(0)$ tells you that you have an $SU(2)$ singlet. The second set of parentheses is the rep under the $SU(3)$ part.

Looking at dynkin labels of different reps you find that $(01)$ belongs to the antifundamental representation of $SU(3)$.

Finally there is the question of the $U(1)$ charge. This is not uniquely defined in the notation you gave. So $(0)(01)$ can either be a charge $-1/3$ up antiquark or charge $2/3$ down antiquark.

The $U(1)$ charges are uniquely fixed once you identify *one single* state and define its $U(1)$ charge. Here, one could for example take the positron. It has $(0)(00)$ and therefore is unique in $\overline{ \mathbf 5} + \mathbf{10}$. Knowing it has Hypercharge $Y = 1$ allows you to define a linear combination of operators (corresponding to a certain sum of dynkin indices) as *the* Hypercharge and use this to determine all other $U(1)$ charges.

EDIT to adress comment:
Let's look at the representation with $(01)$ as a highest root (which is the antifundamental). From that we can subtract a simple root $(-1 2)$ to get
$$ (01) \to (1 -1)$$
from which we can subract the other simple root $(2 -1)$ to get
$$ (1 -1) \to (-1 0)$$
Having only negative or 0 entries this is the bottom of the rep. Since there was no branching we can summarize
$$ (0 1) \overset{\alpha_2}{\to} (1 -1) \overset{\alpha_1}{\to} (-1 0 )$$
We see we have found a three dimensional rep. Now there is another three dimensional rep, the fundamental $(1 0)$. Which of these we call fundamental and which antifundamental is arbitrary, since they swap roles in the group homomorphism $T \to T^*$ (which, *iirc* corresponds to the non-trivial symmetry of the Dynkin diagram).

So once we set the rep starting form $(1 0)$ as the fundamental, the rep starting from $(0 1)$ is the antifundamental, containing the states 
$$\overline{\mathbf 3} = {(0 1), (1 -1), (-1 0)}$$
and finding $(0 1)$ in that list makes us identify it as a member of $\overline{\mathbf 3}$.

P.S.: We could also have seen that $\overline{\mathbf 3}$ and $\mathbf 3$ are conjugate from seeing that if $(a b)$ is a member of $\overline{\mathbf 3}$, $(-a -b)$ is a member of $\mathbf 3$!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the (01) part of the notation, why do (0)(01), (0)(1-1) and (0)(-10) all represent an 1/3 antiquark?

Comment: @user41746 I expanded my answer to reply.

Comment: Thank you! But something is still unclear; how do you assign a $Y$ and $I_3$ value? In the review to state $(0)(01)$ is seen as a charge 0 lepton doublet, when it is projected from a $\overline{5}$ weight while it becomes a $(0)(01)$, when it is projected from the $(1-110)$ root of the $10$ representation of su$(5)$!?

Comment: $(0)(01)$ is not a lepton doublet. The first $(0)$ tells you it is a weak *singlet*, the fact that $(01)$ belongs to the antifundamental of $SU(3)$ tells you it is an antiquark.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten to write a part of my comment: it is the assignment of the $Y$ value, the hypercharge associated to the U(1), that I don't understand. How do you know that in the projected $\overline{5}$ the hypercharge of (0)(01) is $\overline{Y}=2/3$ while this same state in the projection of the 10 has $\overline{Y}=1/3$? (I derived the Y value from the requirement to match the electric charge, which is the reverse argument...)

Comment: I know that it is already partially explained in your answer, but I still don't understand how you can determine the 4 components of the hypercharge axis by just one constraint. Why does the positron has hypercharge 1?